# Adding to Rails Database with Drop Down Menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, drop-down-menu

I have been fooling around with my code for a couple days now, so I finally decided to come here for some help. I am creating a website for my job where an administrator can create a new user if they choose to. Any regular employee, however, cannot. I think visually, the best looking way to go about this is using a drop down menu, where they can choose the new user to be an administrator (director) or employee (front or back of house). My issue is linking the choice chosen when creating the user to update the 'admin' field in my database. Right now I have a boolean admin column in the database (I have been following the Michael Hartl Rails tutorial). My logic, was just to set the administrator as true in the boolean field and false otherwise, but nothing I am trying is correctly doing this. The default is set to false right now. I have added the code to the "Creating a New User" html code and the file that was created once I added the admin column in my database. If I need to include any additional code, please let me know! I just feel like nothing I am reading online is efficiently answering my question. Thanks in advance!

Sign up HTML file:

```
    <!-- sign up page. Will need to add front/back
    of house and only allow directors to use this-->
    .active {
    ...
    line-height: 200em;
    ....
    }

    <% provide(:title, 'Create New Team Member') %>
    <h1>Create New Team Member</h1>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.label :Duty %>
        <%= f.select(:admin, [["Director", "true"],
            ["Front of House", "false"], ["Back of House", "false"]], class:     
            'form-control') %>

        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Password Confirmation" %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %

        <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

      <% end %>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Admin column file:

```
    class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, default: false
      end
    end
```

Comment: You should reconsider using boolean values to differentiate users. Consider, instead, using the concept of role, which can succinctly summarize multiple abilities, states, etc. Think about what happens when you want to add some capability to your users table beyond 'admin' and how messy it gets to check multiple columns when you want to authorize your users to do different things in your application.

Comment: Yes, I also thought about that. So would you just recommend deleting the boolean column and creating a string or integer column? What do you suggest?

Comment: That would be the easiest way to do it, but you could also add a `role_id` field in your `users` table and a `roles` table with `id`, `role` and `description` columns, which is more proper from the standpoint of database design. Using role also primes sets you up to use authorization gems like CanCanCan etc.

Comment: Alright, I really do appreciate your feedback, I'm going to start looking at it from a role_id standpoint.